# Split lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm traying to create a prolog code to split two lists, and that do not work. Why?

```
append([], List, List).
append([Head|Tail], List, [Head|Rest]) :- append(Tail, List, Rest).

split([],N,[]).
split([H|L1], N, L2):- N \= 0, append(L2, H, X), split(L1, N-1, L2).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish? Sample input and desired results would be most useful in help us help you.

If you're trying to extract the prefix of a list (the 1st N items), the simplest way is to use Prolog's intrinisics:

```
split( Xs , N , Pfx ) :-
  length(Pfx,N) ,
  append(Pfx,_,Xs)
  .
```

Comment: Every Prolog has length/2, so better use `split(Xs,N,Prefix) :- length(Prefix,N), append(Prefix,_,Xs).`

Comment: @jschimpf - good call. answer modified to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem: `N-1` doesn't get evaluated to a numeric expression, you need to explicitly state what you want:

```
... M is N-1, split(L1, M, L2).
```

To get the first N elements from a list, append/3 seems really useless. Try instead

```
split([], _, []).
split(_, 0, []).
split([H|L1], N, [H|L2]) :- N > 0, M is N-1, split(L1, M, L2).
```